# Subdomains that don't exist are indexed by Google - Zombie subdomain removal via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm experiencing an unusual issue where Google is indexing subdomains of my site that don't exist. It looks like these 'subdomains' are created from misspellings such as `w.` `ww.`. There's even some instances of `http://abc.www.example.com` being indexed.

My main concern here is with content duplication in the SERPS as there are several of these non existent / zombie subdomains indexed by Google. I want these subdomains to either drop out of the SERPS or be redirected to the secure www. version of the website.

I'm experienced in web development, but server configuration and `.htaccess` / mod Rewrite rules are not my biggest strength.

There's currently a rewrite rule to force https across the site - could this be amended to force the zombie subdomains to redirect to `https://www.`? If it is possible, can I ensure it doesn't effect real subdomains of the site?

Current `.htaccess` redirect :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is not surprising at all. Your http server will deliver the default host whenever a hostname is requested that is not defined. That is normal and _documented_ behavior. You can block that if you want to, but that is an explicit step you have to take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the server delivering the default host in this case but I've never experienced Google indexing such requests.

Comment: Google accepts all pages into its index that it finds referres to and that do not block indexing. You can try to find out where those links are generated, most likely some randomizing link lister (click highjacking, typo highjacking, ...), but in the end that is not of interest since you cannot prevent that. Instead you can block google indexing the pages, just define your `robots.txt` file such that the robot won't index those non existing pages.

Comment: Yes agreed! It's not something that's linked out to from the site itself so I'm not going to waste time finding the cause if it can't be prevented. I've added canonical tags to all pages and have added individual rewrite conditions to .htaccess to 301 the pages to the main ones. I'll see what can be done at robots.txt level but as these zombie subdomains don't actually exist as subdomains I'm not sure editing the robots.txt in the root will be the best way.

Comment: From a technical point of view those requests target _valid and existing_ hosts, since they receive an answer from your site. So it is up to you to prevent that if you want to. Not by redirecting, but by blocking, though redirecting them might have the same effect for the search engines, since they do not follow such external redirections. About the `robots.txt` file: where else would you want to control search robots?

Comment: Hi arkascha, since the subdomains don't actually exist, the robots.txt file would need to be in the root so I'm not sure how I could easily block the crawl of all pages on abc.example.com? I thought the implementation of canonical tags placed on each page should go some way to help de index the pages and get around the issue. I know using the canonical tag can help to prevent problems caused by duplicate content indexed by Google. Of course, let me know if I've missed something and it is possible with robots.txt though.

Comment: 1. there is no such thing as a "subdomain". There are hostnames. DNS records for host names point to IP addresses. 2. stop thinking in a physical file hierarchy when it comes to content of a http host: why do you think that you can have only one `/robots.txt` path in your setup? You can internally requite such requests to whatever you want, it does not even have to be a file, be it static or a script. 3. you should define your existing hosts as specific hosts and use the 1st defined host (which acts as the fallback) only as a fallback. In there you can block what and how you want.

Answer (score 1):

To address the comments... You can't block *hostnames* (subdomains) in `robots.txt` if all subdomains are pointing to the same place (the same site), unless you internally rewrite those requests to a different `robots-block.txt` file. However, `robots.txt` doesn't necessarily prevent *indexing*, it prevents *crawling*, and if these subdomains are already indexed, then they are going to remain indexed for "a long time" if you simply block *crawling* (since the search bots cannot revisit the URLs to update their cache).

Are you on a shared server? Or do you have your own? This will only be a "default host" issue if this is your own server and your site is the first (or only) host defined on it. (This is rare to be a shared server issue and would arguably be a misconfiguration of that server.) Otherwise, this sounds like you have a "wildcard" subdomain defined in DNS (and perhaps a corresponding `ServerAlias` in the server config).

Remove the "wildcard subdomain" and it will resolve your issue.

---

#### What is a wildcard subdomain...

Specifically, the wildcard subdomain consists of two parts (as with any public subdomain/hostname):

1. An `A` (or `CNAME`) record in the public DNS zone file of the form:

   ```
   *.example.com.  A  <IP-ADDRESS-OF-YOUR-SERVER>
   ```

   Or,

   ```
   *.example.com.  CNAME  example.com.
   ```

   (Where the `*.` prefix indicates the wildcard - it can only be a *prefix*.)

   The DNS record enables requests for `<anything>.example.com` to resolve to your server (IP address).
2. An entry in your server config that instructs your server to accept requests to `<anything>.example.com` and how the request should be handled (eg. by what `<VirtualHost>`). If you have multiple sites (virtualhosts) configured in your webserver then there should be an explicit directive in the appropriate `<VirtualHost>` container of the form:

   ```
   ServerAlias *.example.com
   ```

   However, if the above is not explicitly defined and there are no directives/virtualhosts that block such requests then a request for `<anything>.example.com` will be caught by the first defined `<VirtualHost>` container (the *default*). On a server that hosts multiple sites this may or may not be *your* site! This is arguably a misconfiguration (unless explicitly by design) - there should normally be a *default* `<VirtualHost>` container that catches requests for "non-canonical" (unknown) hosts and effectively discards (or redirects) them.

So, the removal of the DNS entry (#1) is sufficient to publicly disable the wildcard subdomain (and prevent the hostname being indexed). However, unless the server config is also updated (#2) then it's still possible the hostname can be accessed.

---

Otherwise you can redirect (or block) any non-canonical hosts in `.htaccess`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above would send a 403 Forbidden for any request that is not for `example.com` or `www.example.com`.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
> ```

This is not correct. It only canonicalises `http://example.com`. It won't canonicalise/redirect `http://www.example.com` or `https://example.com` since the two conditions are implicitly AND'd. You need to `OR` the two conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

In order to match `example.com` *or* `http`.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer @MrWhite. I appreciate the explanation as this isn't my biggest strength. The site is hosted on a shared server but also utilizes a CDN, so it's entirely possible the DNS settings there have a "wildcard" subdomain set up - so I'll definitely check that out first. I've taken over the site from a previous developer who is no longer contactable - I'm not sure why a wildcard subdomain would have been set up if it is the case - are there any benefits to configuring a wildcard, other than having the ability to access the site from any hostname?

Comment: How do you "Remove the wildcard subdomain"? I am also experiencing this issue and I asked a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77558953/how-to-remove-the-wildcard-subdomain-on-apache-to-prevent-google-from-indexing-s to discover how to remove the wildcard subdomain, and see if that fixes my issue.

Comment: @threatlevel_midnight "are there any benefits to configuring a wildcard, other than having the ability to access the site from any hostname?" - Yes, that is the purpose... it effectively allows you to manage multiple subdomains in your application without having to modify DNS/server config each time. However, unless you are managing these subdomains in your app then a wildcard subdomain could potentially cause "duplicate content" issues - which would seem to be what's happening here.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya I've updated my answer with more information about what a "wildcard subdomain" is and potentially how to remove it. Having had a look at your other question, you certainly do seem to have a "wildcard subdomain" configured (in DNS at least), since a DNS lookup on `<anything>.your-domain.com` returns an `A` record pointing to the same IP address as your domain apex. However, that IP address also resolves to your site, which suggests this is your own server and you don't have a "default" virtualhost configured that blocks such "non-canonical" requests.

Comment: I have an A Record @MrWhite, with a `*`, as seen in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEk6d.png. I guess I need to remove that and then configure Apache Virtual Hosts for each of the subdomains that are being problematic by Google indexing them (`w`, `ww.w`, etc.) I do not need subdomains and I would like to have `https://w.example.com/post-entry/` redirecting to `https://example.com/post-entry/`, and  `https://ww.w.example.com/post-entry/` redirecting to `https://example.com/post-entry/`. I have no idea where Google found those subdomains `w` and `ww.w` that I never configured on Apache.

Comment: My domain registrar tool does not seem to like it when I remove the `* A Record`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDkqA.png.

Comment: I posted the solution that worked for me @MrWhite, in UPDATE 7 of my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77558953/how-to-remove-the-wildcard-subdomain-on-apache-to-prevent-google-from-indexing-s, and also in the answer to my own question at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/143778/how-to-remove-the-wildcard-subdomain-on-apache-to-prevent-google-from-indexing-s. Thank you!